# How to invoke a button click or event in a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a class to hold some extra behavior for `DataGrid`. I will simplify what it really does because it's not important for now.

When the user presses `Up` or `Down` keys, it will execute a private local method of `DataGridHelper` class; that's done. However, when the user presses `Right` or `Left` I want to fire an event or a `Button` click from outside. When user presses Left or Right it will change the current page(redo the search). I want to reuse this `PreviewKeyDown` in many `DataGrid`.

I have some idea, but I'm confused. I would create another `DependencyProperty` to pass the Button id, so I have to search in the Visual Tree, but I don't know if this is the best approach. I would like to do something like:

```
<DataGrid x:name="myGrid" 
          Help:DataGridHelper.CustomGrid="True" 
          Help:DataGridHelper.OnLeftRight="myGrid_OnLeftRight"  />

private void myGrid_OnLeftRight(object sender, CustomEventArgs e) 
{
     if(e.Key == "Left").....
}
```

This what I've done so far:

```
 public class DataGridHelper
 {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomGridProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CustomGrid", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, CustomGridCallback));

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(DataGrid))]
        public static bool GetCustomGrid(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(CustomGridProperty);
        }


        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(DataGrid))]
        public static void SetCustomGrid(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CustomGridProperty, value);
        }

        private static void CustomGridCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           var dataGrid = (DataGrid)d;

           if ((bool)e.NewValue == false)
           {
               dataGrid.PreviewKeyDown -= DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown;
           }
           else
           {
              dataGrid.PreviewKeyDown += DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown;
           }
      }     

      private static void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
       {
          if (e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up)
              DoMyStuff(); // static method in DataGridHelper class

          if(e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right)
             // here I want to invoke a button click
            // or here I want to invoke a passed method from view
      }
}
```

I don't want to create a class like `MyDataGrid : DataGrid`, because I use MahApps, and some style won't work so.

Comment: You shouldn't invoke a `Button` click. In WPF, you should use view-model's `ICommand`s that will be bound to your view.

Comment: I thought so. I need some help to do what I wrote in the XAML part.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is wrong.

A simple general rule to remember in WPF: **If you're using an event in code-behind to call business logic, you're doing it wrong.**

You should use Input Bindings or Attached Behaviors/Blend SDK Interaction Behaviors to get the behaviour you want by binding the events or specific button gestures to `Commands` in your `ViewModel`.

In your XAML somewhere (`DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` for example):

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="LeftButtonUp">
           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command={Binding LeftButtonActionCommand}/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand nothing for now. I will give a look in some information about what you said.

Comment: I do have code-behind, but it only calls ViewModel methods, but I don't use ICommand

Comment: Then you are not using `MVVM` correctly as you have a hard-dependency between the `View` and `ViewModel`. As I said - it's a sign you're doing it wrong. Have a look at http://www.wpftutorial.net/ to give you some guidance.